# Can I use setting joint compound to fix a a plaster ceiling with metal mesh lath?

Tags: ceiling

Plaster repair with drywall compound? Will it work? I put fiber tape over the hole and filled it in with dura bond. Will it last or not? I need to figure this out fast. I have never worked with the plaster. But I am very good with sheetrock finishing. Can anyone give me some answers please.????

Answer (score 1):

I would use the faster setting durabond mix it a little dryer than what you would use on walls and press it into the metal. The faster setting is a harder to sand but it will hold up and look fine when painted. My mom's house has the steel mesh with cement, It is really hard to work with because the cement eats the metal disks and the metal eats the cement cutting wheels. But it holds up better than wood lath.
If you have any areas that are sagging from water damage I have had good luck adding some 2x4 between rafters, breaking the cement (or plaster in your case) and pulling the mesh up with screws then putting in fresh durabond 20 or 30 minute fast setting. I did this shortly after my dad passed and it still looks great after 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a bonding concern (assuming clean plaster), so I'd use Easy Sand. It's also a setting-type joint compound, but it isn't as rock hard as DuraBond. It will bond very well to plaster and lath, and it won't shrink much at all. I'd go with the 45- or 90-minute varieties. The faster ones get difficult to work in a hurry. Also, use cool water. Warm water accelerates the cure rate dramatically.

You can certainly use a setting compound as a base and use lightweight premixed 
compound as a finish coat.

Comment: I do agree with the cool water 1 time I was in a huge hurry so I used warm water and 30 Minuit mix it was done in 15 maybe 20 but it held fine but cleanup on my pans was almost not worth the time as it was rock solid in way less time. Easy sand is best for a topping , IMHO